# Add Font Family Feature to CKEditor Toolbar in Angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor, toolbar, font-family, ckeditor5

Sadly I could not manage to add the font family feature to the CKEditor's toolbar in Angular.

I'm getting the following error in the console:

> toolbarview-item-unavailable: The requested toolbar item is
>   unavailable. Read more:
>   https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-toolbarview-item-unavailable

```
{name: "fontFamily"}
```

Here is how my project looks like:

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { CkeditorComponent } from './ckeditor/ckeditor.component';
...

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [
        ...
        CkeditorComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        CKEditorModule,
        ...
    ],
    ...
} )
```

**ckeditor.component.ts**

```
import * as BalloonEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon';

@Component( {
    ...
} )

export class CkeditorComponent {
    public Editor = BalloonEditor;

    public editorConfig = {
        fontFamily: {
          options: [
            'default',
            'Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif',
            'Ubuntu Mono, Courier New, Courier, monospace'
          ]
        },
        toolbar: [
          'heading', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'fontFamily'
        ]
    };
}
```

**ckeditor.component.html**

```
<ckeditor 
  [editor]="Editor" 
  [config]="editorConfig"
  data="<p>Hello world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I replied to you in the [GH issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/26#issuecomment-436926435), the `FontFamily` plugin is, unfortunately, not present in the `Balloon Editor` build. Thus you have two options:

1. Build an editor with a custom plugin outside of the package following [this guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html) and then move that editor to the angular repository. The rest is described in the [Angular integration guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html).
2. Build editor from source following [these steps](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/26). While the first approach is officially supported I can't tell you that building from source will work as I didn't spend much time investigating it and its edge-cases.
3. Use the  [Document Editor](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/document-editor.html), which contains the `FontFamily` plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your help,

**I started to create my own custom build based on Balloon**. Here you can find where I stuck right now: [GH >>](https://github.com/webpreneur/ckeditor5-build-balloon/commits/master)

P.S.: I added an **error_logs** directory, inside you can find the error log which I got.

Comment: It's because of incorrect import - `import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font';` should be `import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';` We don't expose default entry points in our source packages since they might be used in different ways.

Comment: I've already commited the fix to the [custom balloon editor repo](https://github.com/webpreneur/ckeditor5-custom-build-balloon) and also successfully installed the custom build from GH and imported into my Angular 6 project.

Thank you very much for your help,